# Issues with CORS when fetching data using Vue with Apollo Composable

Tags: vue.js, nginx, cors

### Problem:

I'm encountering CORS issues while trying to fetch data using Vue with Apollo Composable. The server is responsive, and GraphQL Playground and Postman return the expected data. However, in my development environment, everything works fine, but on production, I'm facing issues. Below are the error messages and details:

#### Error Messages:

##### Mozilla:

```
A request to a non-origin resource has been blocked: the "Same Origin Policy" does not allow loading remote resources from "http://127.0.0.1:8080/graphql/" (failed CORS request). Status code: (null).
```

[image: mozilla error]

##### Brave:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/graphql/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

[image: brave error]

##### Error Details:

Mozilla request header OPTIONS (prod, not working)

```
OPTIONS /graphql undefined
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Referer: http://10.0.129.33/
Origin: http://10.0.129.33
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Sec-GPC: 1
```

Mozilla request header POST (prod, not working)

```
POST /graphql undefined
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://10.0.129.33/
content-type: application/json
authorization: Bearer
Content-Length: 354
Origin: http://10.0.129.33
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Sec-GPC: 1
```

Mozilla request header POST (dev, working)

```
POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
content-type: application/json
authorization: Bearer
Content-Length: 354
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
DNT: 1
Sec-GPC: 1
```

#### Configuration:

##### Specification:

- Ubuntu 23.10 Server
- Nginx
- API served via gunicorn and uvicorn
- UFW with port 8080 allowed (API port)

##### apollo.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    service: {
      name: 'docsygen',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/graphql/',
      fetchOptions: {
        mode: 'no-cors',
      },
    },
    includes: [
      'src/**/*.vue',
      'src/**/*.js',
    ],
  },
}
```

##### main.js

```
import {createApp, h, provide} from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from "./router.js";
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import {store} from "./vuex/store.js";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/graphql/',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token') || ''}`
  },
  fetchOptions: {
    mode: 'cors',
  },
  fetch: fetch,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
})

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache,
})

const app = createApp(
  {
    setup() {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
    },
    render: () => h(App),
  }
)

app.use(router).use(store).mount('#app');
```

##### CORS (FastApi)

```
origins = [
    "http://localhost:5173",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:80",
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:5000",
    "10.0.229.136", // postman
    "http://10.0.129.33" // frontend 
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["*"],
)
```

##### Nginx Config (backend)

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/sosaymon/delegation-generator/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name 10.0.129.33 api.xyz.tech;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/sosaymon/delegation-generator/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/sosaymon/delegation-generator/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

###### Additional info:

- Development environment works fine.
- Server is responsive on production (Postman return the expected data)
- CORS middleware is configured on the backend.
- Nginx is set up for proxying requests

Comment: Based on the error, it sounds like you need to add `http://127.0.0.1:8080` to your list of allowed CORS origins

Comment: @yoduh No; it looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8080` is the Web origin of the backend.

Comment: @yoduh yeah, `http://127.0.0.1:8080` is the Web origin